# Type Alt Characters in Google Chrome Browser Without Switching Tabs

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters

How do you type special characters in Google Chrome when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> is a shortcut to switch to that tab?

I've been unable to find an answer to this online. I'm aware that in Linux I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and type the Unicode number for special characters, however I already know the alt codes for common characters I use. Such as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `0252` for `ü`.

In Chrome, when I type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `0252` it switches to the second tab, fifth tab, and then second tab again. I've tried using either <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (switches tabs), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (nothing happens), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (OS shortcut), and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> (nothing happens). <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is on for all of these, of course.

Comment: Which OS and what keyboard are you using? Are you typing on the address bar?

Comment: Using a full size dell Windows keyboard (SK-8115) with a numpad. Using CentOS Linux. I am not typing in the address bar, I was typing in a comment/reply box on a website.

Comment: I"m having the same problem. Never had an issue simply using `Alt`+`13` and `Alt` + `14` to display music notes in Facebook posts. Yet as of a few months ago the repsective combinations started changing tabs when using `L. Alt` using `R. Alt` does nothing but let *numpad* buttons signal the numbers directly.  It's anoying enough that I, too, am seeking to fix this. The issue exists in much more than just the Chrome web browser. Any Chrome based app experiences the issue too. Might be a gnome or xinput change too, it's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>. You should see an underlined `u`. Type in the alt code, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

I found on Wikipedia (like ©, etc...),that you can enter it specially on chrome. The Copyrights symbol can be entered by pressing:

- Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0169</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>
- Linux: <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.
- Chrome OS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>a9</kbd>, then <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>.
- HTML: `&copy;` or `&#169;`

(Copied from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_symbol#Typing_the_character))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).